# Why my threads perform the same amount of work in different times?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance-testing

I have a simple multithreaded application in Java which looks like this:

```
class MyThreads extends Thread{
    public void run() {
        {
            // some thread initializations

            // every thread reads 2 files (its own files, 
            // so node 0 will read A0.txt and B0.txt 
            // and node 1 will read A1.txt and B1.txt)
            // he files have sizes between 10-20MB. 
            // A's files contain different information for different nodes (A0.txt != A1.txt),
            // but B's files are the same(B0.txt has 
            // the same info as B1.txt). This is just a scenario.

            // it stores the data that was 
            // read before in the memory.
            // Again, i know B can be shared since 
            // it has the same info in both threads, but it's not.
        }

        {
            // simple computation on the data retrieved 
            // (addition, multiplication, etc)
            // I assume there is no need to synchronize 
            // the threads since they apply operations on their own data.
            // Here, every thread executes the same number of operations
        }

        {
            // writing the results on different files. This phase in unimportant.
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // start 4 threads
    }
}
```

When testing the performance for the initialization part, computation part I got these strange results:

```
2016-03-11-NodeThread:1 time[2318] tag[initialization]
2016-03-11-NodeThread:0 time[2379] tag[initialization]
2016-03-11-NodeThread:2 time[2474] tag[initialization]
2016-03-11-NodeThread:3 time[2481] tag[initialization]
2016-03-11-NodeThread:2 time[30ms] tag[computation]
2016-03-11-NodeThread:1 time[6ms] tag[computation]
2016-03-11-NodeThread:3 time[7ms] tag[computation]
2016-03-11-NodeThread:0 time[6ms] tag[computation]
```

As one can see the computation for NodeThread:2 took 30ms but for the other nodes took less than 10 ms.

Though, after inserting a barrier between the initialization and the computation I get good results:

```
2016-03-11-NodeThread:1 time[2318] tag[initialization]
2016-03-11-NodeThread:0 time[2379] tag[initialization]
2016-03-11-NodeThread:2 time[2474] tag[initialization]
2016-03-11-NodeThread:3 time[2481] tag[initialization]
2016-03-11-NodeThread:2 time[30ms] tag[computation]
2016-03-11-NodeThread:1 time[33ms] tag[computation]
2016-03-11-NodeThread:3 time[29ms] tag[computation]
2016-03-11-NodeThread:0 time[31ms] tag[computation]
```

My question is: if the threads don't communicate at all, they read from different parts of the disk, and they perform the same amount of computation, why the need of synchronising them before computing? My guess would be that a caching is involved, but I can't explain why.

NB. The machine where I tested the code has more that 4 cores, no other cpu consuming processes were running. For measuring the time I used perf4j like this.

```
    class MyThreads extends Thread{
        public void run() {
            {
                StopWatch stopWatch = new Log4JStopWatch();
                // some thread initializations

                // every thread reads 2 files (its own files,
                // so node 0 will read A0.txt and B0.txt
                // and node 1 will read A1.txt and B1.txt)
                // he files have sizes between 10-20MB.
                // A's files contain different information for different nodes (A0.txt != A1.txt),
                // but B's files are the same(B0.txt has
                // the same info as B1.txt). This is just a scenario.

                // it stores the data that was
                // read before in the memory.
                // Again, i know B can be shared since
                // it has the same info in both threads, but it's not.
                stopWatch.stop("initialization");
// barrier
            }

            {
                StopWatch stopWatch = new Log4JStopWatch();
                // simple computation on the data retrieved
                // (addition, multiplication, etc)
                // I assume there is no need to synchronize
                // the threads since they apply operations on their own data.
                // Here, every thread executes the same number of operations
                stopWatch.stop("computation");
            }

            {
                // writing the results on different files. This phase in unimportant.
            }
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            // start 4 threads
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think you need synchronization? All you have shown, is that synchronization makes things slower, which in itself isn't a surprise.

Comment: Are you running Threads using ExecutorService? File size may influence Thread execution time. From my observation number of threads should be equal to number of cores (or be + 1 due to context switching). Do you synchronize the Threads on common monitor objects or not? Please post more code instead of comments.

Comment: Which one is your question? the one in the title or the one in the text? They have almost nothing in common.

Comment: The one in the title, sorry.

Comment: The number of threads to use is a science in its own. It starts with the fact that different versions of Java might give you different "number of cores" for the same hardware.

Comment: @Jägermeister That's interesting. Could you please post any source for this analysis?

Comment: @Jens Schauder, the point is, I don't need synchronisation, but the correct amount of time a thread should spend is 30ms not 5. Why is spending 5ms? ( I computed manually the number of operations and considering 10^7 operations should perform in 0.1 sec, from there I got the time). And i didn;t show you that synch. makes things slower. What interests me is what happens AFTER the synchronisation, NOT BEFORE.

Comment: @mlewandowski See http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue220.html for details.

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess, because one would lots more details to be really sure, but what is probably happening is that your first thread executes some code so often that it gets compiled and possibly optimized by the Hotspot compiler and other magic stuff build in your JVM.

Your synchronization attempt probably prevents this from happening, possibly because the threads are done with their computation before the compiling happens, because they now start all at about the same time.